# What is the program flow to get multiple SPI ports to run at the same time?

Tags: pic, spi

What is the program flow to get multiple SPI ports to run at the same time?  I am a linear thinker so it's hard to think of doing more than one task to completion at a time.  I need to read two 24-bit ADCs at the same time (or close to it).  The SPI ports will clock at 40MHz and I need to take 1,000,000 (1M) readings per second.
The processor is a PIC32MZ2048ECH 144-pin.  I can either use just C or C with the Free RTOS.
The ADCs are ADS1675's by Texas Instruments.

Comment: Could you please tell the ADC you want to use?

Comment: I think you're going to need a bigger boat, unless the PIC has at least dual synchronous UART inputs. What you want to do is too fast for bit-banging, with that processor.

Comment: You can start one SPI then start the other, then come back to get the results from the first, etc. If you do them sequentially you'll probably run out of time (you may anyway).

Comment: The PIC32 has a DMA controller. If I recall correctly Microchip has a reference example of using this with the SPI peripheral.

Comment: Have you picked an ADC yet?  It could help answer the question depending on what sort of modes it has for reading out fast.

Comment: And what will you be doing with the 1 MSPS readings?

Comment: @justing : I will be using a couple of ADS1675IPAG ADCs.  Their top external SPI clock rate is 40MHz.  Internally can go faster but uses LVDS outputs. I would have to convert them to 3.3V logic and from differential to single ended signals to be used by the PIC32MZ.
I'm actually using 11 SPI devices.  9 of them are only accessed during setup.  I'm using SPI1 for the 40MHz devices at this time, and SPI2 for the 20MHz devices.  For the SS lines I'm using RA0-RA3 into a couple of 74LVC138's.
With the readings I will be converting phase and voltage to LCR measurements to catch transients.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this before (around 2006), I need to speed up the programming of SPI flash devices in our production and we want to do parallel SPI operation for all the 8 flash device. So thinking out of the box, what I did is:

- create a fixture which can slot in 8 devices
- the CS pin, CLK, MOSI are all connected in common to all device. So all flash devices, receive the commands from these pins at the same time.
- For reading, I used a full port (PORTB0 to PORTB7) to connect to the individual MISO of the flash devices.

This was a success. It used SPI bitbanging and involves bit-shifting to form the data read from the port. But still very fast than accessing or reading an SPI device one at a time.

But I see that you are using PIC32MZ2048 and only 2 SPI device, maybe you can try exploring the QSI (Quad Serial Interface) if it can achieve your needs without resorting to bitbanging.

Answer (score 0):

At these speeds you will be taxing the PIC32 near the top of it's capabilities if you have anything else to do. My approach to the problem would be to setup DMA triggers for reading/writing larger chunks at a time (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170924/receiving-spi-data-via-dma-on-pic32) and relying heavily on interrupts and state machines.